# bootstrap-datepicker view the ready html

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I bootstrap-datepicker

I want to change its design at css file

What I would like to see is the ready calendar, ie to see the HTML code that creates the datepicker plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question completely.  But to the see the html of a date-picker all you have to do is navigate to a page that has a date-picker open it up, then right click and view the source.

Here is the html for a twitter bootstrap date picker I found at

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

```
<div class="datepicker dropdown-menu" style="display: block; top: 345px; left: 741.5px;"><div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block;"><table class=" table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">February 2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr><tr><th class="dow">Su</th><th class="dow">Mo</th><th class="dow">Tu</th><th class="dow">We</th><th class="dow">Th</th><th class="dow">Fr</th><th class="dow">Sa</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="day  old">29</td><td class="day  old">30</td><td class="day  old">31</td><td class="day ">1</td><td class="day ">2</td><td class="day ">3</td><td class="day ">4</td></tr><tr><td class="day ">5</td><td class="day ">6</td><td class="day ">7</td><td class="day ">8</td><td class="day ">9</td><td class="day ">10</td><td class="day ">11</td></tr><tr><td class="day ">12</td><td class="day ">13</td><td class="day ">14</td><td class="day ">15</td><td class="day  active">16</td><td class="day ">17</td><td class="day ">18</td></tr><tr><td class="day ">19</td><td class="day ">20</td><td class="day ">21</td><td class="day ">22</td><td class="day ">23</td><td class="day ">24</td><td class="day ">25</td></tr><tr><td class="day ">26</td><td class="day ">27</td><td class="day ">28</td><td class="day ">29</td><td class="day  new">1</td><td class="day  new">2</td><td class="day  new">3</td></tr><tr><td class="day  new">4</td><td class="day  new">5</td><td class="day  new">6</td><td class="day  new">7</td><td class="day  new">8</td><td class="day  new">9</td><td class="day  new">10</td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none;"><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2012</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="month">Jan</span><span class="month active">Feb</span><span class="month">Mar</span><span class="month">Apr</span><span class="month">May</span><span class="month">Jun</span><span class="month">Jul</span><span class="month">Aug</span><span class="month">Sep</span><span class="month">Oct</span><span class="month">Nov</span><span class="month">Dec</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="datepicker-years" style="display: none;"><table class="table-condensed"><thead><tr><th class="prev">‹</th><th colspan="5" class="switch">2010-2019</th><th class="next">›</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="7"><span class="year old">2009</span><span class="year">2010</span><span class="year">2011</span><span class="year active">2012</span><span class="year">2013</span><span class="year">2014</span><span class="year">2015</span><span class="year">2016</span><span class="year">2017</span><span class="year">2018</span><span class="year">2019</span><span class="year old">2020</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
```